# Error message when trying to connect database

Tags: python, mysql, macos, operating-system, macos-catalina

I'm getting such an error message while connecting on a mac os.

2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (61 Connection refused)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a user and grant privileges to access db.

```sql
CREATE USER 'general'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'general'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

Here, my user is `general` and password is `1234`
If you have already created user skip first step and replace `general` with your **username** and `1234` with your **password**